# Texinput without whitespace?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I need to alert when user enters white space while filling the textınput field. By the time doing this I do not want keyboard to disappear. I have no clue how to do this any idea?

Comment: Means you don't need any white space in between the text?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt yes. But after I alert or before I want user input stay there without whitespace. Like if user did enters 'Intteligience' + ' ', then I will alert but when user closes that alert input has to stay like 'Intelligience and s/he can continue typing and marker will be staying blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` for this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  View, TextInput } from "react-native";


class App extends Component {

  state = {
     text : ''
  }

  hasWhiteSpace(s) {
    let regSpace= new RegExp(/\s/);
    // Check for white space
    if (regSpace.test(s)) {
      //your logic
      alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
      return false;
    } else {
       this.setState({ text:s })
    }
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
            onChangeText={text => {
            this.hasWhiteSpace(text);
          }}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

working example

https://codesandbox.io/embed/04jl3800vw

Comment: Thank you. I did this as well. But I want to do this in a way like that. After I alert or before I want user input stay there without whitespace. Like if user did enters 'Intteligience' + ' ', then I will alert but when user closes that alert input has to stay like 'Intelligience and s/he can continue typing and marker will be staying blinking

Comment: instead of alert, it is always better to show toast message (notification).
something like this ... https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify

Comment: Thank you for both returns. I appreciate you mentioned toast message. It is actually  better than alert in a situation like this.